# Confusion - How does a object move, when there is no force acting on it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration

#### Question:

When for a moving object, $a=0$ it actually means (resultant Force=0) and that there's no pure force acting on it, and it's here where I get confused:

If there's no pure force acting on the object, what makes the object move?

Comment: It's a physical fact that an object moving at constant velocity (e.g., constant speed and constant direction) has no NET force acting on it.  This is a fact that you should just take for granted.  To do otherwise means that you will continue to be confused by Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: It would be good for the title to be more descriptive.

Comment: a = 0 just means the object's speed isn't changing. It doesn't mean it has zero speed.

Comment: [Newton’s First Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion): “Every body continues in its state of rest, or of uniform motion in a straight line, unless it is compelled to change that state by forces impressed upon it.”

Answer (score 5):

Inertia is the tendency of an object's motion to remain unchanged. All matter has inertia, and cannot change velocity spontaneously (with no force acting upon it). If the object is in motion, it will stay in motion, if it's at rest, it will stay at rest. It's the natural tendency of objects to continue moving exactly how they are already - changing the direction or speed of motion requires some interventional force.

It's perhaps more clear if you look at the question the other way - if an object is moving, and no forces are acting on it, what would make it *stop*?

Comment: @WilliamMartens A vacuum in deep space is a convenient location for thought experiments because there are no pesky external forces like friction, air resistance or gravity. If you push a wheeled object on earth, it is slowed down by friction in the wheels and by air resistance, and eventually comes to a stop. The fact that the object comes to a stop means there must be non-zero forces acting upon it, since if we had F=0, the object would move forever at the same speed in a straight line.

Comment: @WilliamMartens Yes. If there are no forces acting on the object, there is no acceleration, meaning the velocity is constant. The object's speed and direction won't change at all, it'll just move in a straight line.